# How do I call an array in another class?

Tags: java

I am new to programming in java and I have a question you might find silly however no matter how many youtube videos I watch I just cant work out what to do.

Ive created a GUI and i'm getting the text from the text fields and stored them as a string in a variable.

```
String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
        String subject = subjectText.getText();
        String recipient = recipientText.getText();
        String message = messageArea.getText();
```

I then created an array with this data.

```
String [] messageData = {messageId,subject,recipient,message};
```

now i need to call this array to another class where i can then use it. The other class is called "`MessageData`"

Could anyone advise me on what code to use to do this.

Sorry for the basic question, any help would be appreciated

Thanks Again 
Joe

Comment: You don't "call" an array, you *reference* it.

Comment: Why are you trying to learn from youtube videos? Find a real tutorial or buy a book.

Comment: Create a public getArray method in the class of the array which returns the array and then call it from your other class

Comment: The best encapsulated way would be to add a public getter method from the class that owns the messageData member.   Then, provide a reference  to the owning class to your other class where it can call the getter method.

Answer (score 0):

If this is all happening inside a method of your class, then MessageData needs to call the method, and the method needs to `return` the array.  That would look something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String[] getStrings() {
        String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
        String subject = subjectText.getText();
        String recipient = recipientText.getText();
        String message = messageArea.getText();
        String[] messageData = new String[]{messageId, subject, recipient, message};
        return messageData;
    }
}
```

and in MessageData:

```
MyClass thing = new MyClass();
String[] strings = thing.getStrings();
```

Or, if messageData is instead a field of your class, you could write a getter for it.  That would look more like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String[] messageData;

    public void setThingsUp() {
        String messageId = messageIdText.getText();
        String subject = subjectText.getText();
        String recipient = recipientText.getText();
        String message = messageArea.getText();
        messageData = new String[]{messageId, subject, recipient, message};
    }

    public String[] getMessageData() {
        return messageData;
    }
}
```

called thus:

```
MyClass thing = new MyClass();
thing.setThingsUp();
String[] strings = thing.getMessageData();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "use it", you are exeuting a function which get the reference of the string somehow.

You can do it as Carl Manaster does. When they are not in the same class, there are more choices.

In your function within your class

```
use(String[] strings){
    //do sth with strings
}
```

in your calling function `use(messageData);`

Give the function [appropriate accessibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

And there are more ways to share variables. When it comes to multi-threading, use safe ones like queue or message (especially between your backend and ui thread. Do not deal with data in ui thread). Use intent between activities in android.

PS. It seems that your strings has special meanings, so Map may be better for you than a list. You can call `var.get("message1d");` instead of confusing `var[0]`, which you will never recogonie 0's meaning later on.